# Ionic4: Issue with playing audio file in web app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, audio, ionic4

Currently I’m using Ionic 4 with Angular.

I want to have an image when I click it, audio will be played(mp3/wav). I’ve been struggling on it for a week now. Can you help me with the following? What are my options to play audio file in ionic 4, and how to play my audio file in the app?

in Chrome Debug Console, it shows

> "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'My_Audio_File.mp3'"

when I click on the href link that I made of the mp3 file.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home Page
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <audio
        controls
        src="My_Audio_File.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
<p>

    <a href="My_Audio_File.mp3">Debugging: link to the audio</a>
<p>
</ion-content>
```

Chrome Debug Console shows this error when clicking on the href link:

> "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'My_Audio_File.mp3'"

Comment: Where in your project structure is the **My_Audio_File.mp3** file located?

Comment: I’m storing the mp3 in the same directory as the html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cordova-plugin-media` for background Audio play.

```
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';

constructor(private media: Media) { }

// Create a Media instance.  Expects path to file or url as argument
// We can optionally pass a second argument to track the status of the media

const file: MediaObject = this.media.create('file.mp3');

// to listen to plugin events:

file.onStatusUpdate.subscribe(status => console.log(status)); // fires when file status changes

file.onSuccess.subscribe(() => console.log('Action is successful'));

file.onError.subscribe(error => console.log('Error!', error));

// play the file
file.play();

// pause the file
file.pause();
```

Please Refer to this Lick for complete documentation. [Click Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media)